# "." in query string messing up

Tags: mysql

I was working with queries that the data is being used for the meta description.

```
UPDATE cards SET meta_description = 'Amy\'s bugs address labels are printed on recycled label paper. Available in quantities of 30. Each label is 2.5 x 1 inch with rounded corners.' WHERE card_id = 'al007'
```

I have noticed though that the period after paper is shortening the meta description to just `"Amy's bugs address labels are printed on recycled label paper."` If I remove the period the entire description will show up then. Does anyone know how to solve this tiny dilemma?

Comment: How long is the `meta_description` column?

Comment: Define "show up"? How are you determining these facts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the issue is in whatever place you see the results. Most likely, there's a line feed after the period and your device does not support/show multi-line data. When you remove the period, you probably remove the carriage return as well.

Comment: The code performing the output was adding in some extra '.'s As soon I got rid of that it worked just fine. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the period with `'\'`

Since you say, by removing period, the whole sentence is getting updated, I assume there is no problem with the column size.

Comment: Why does a period need escaping?

Comment: @Tom Gullen - Honestly I am not sure. Still investigating on that. As far as I know, I agree with you that period does not need escaping, but maybe the character set is different or something? I really dont know. investigation on the way...

Comment: @Sachin I remember having to do this on a query before, but for the life of me I can't remember if I ever found out why either!  It's strange.

Comment: Yeah it is killing me. I made sure the  char limit was set (150), and that the columns were set right as well.

Comment: @Louis - If you remove first period, then does the data get inserted until it encounters next period?

Comment: If I remove the first period, it will display all of it.   Currently I have this in my jsp file String metadesc=card.getMETADescription();
String sentences[]=metadesc.split("(?<=[a-z])[\\!|\\.]\\s+");
if (sentences.length>0){
    pageContext.setAttribute("description",sentences[0]+".",pageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
}

Comment: @Louis - Then it seems that @Alvaro's answer makes sense. Just check that once.